# AWS Mobile Hub Issue O Linker error - iOS

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, swift3

I followed the mobile hub instructions for setting it up in my app but i seem to be getting these errors when I am trying to compile:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_AWSSNSErrorDomain", referenced from:
      ___88-[AWSPushManager interceptApplication:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:]_block_invoke.239 in AWSMobileHubHelper(AWSPushManager.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AWSLambdaInvoker", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AWSMobileHubHelper(AWSCloudLogic.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AWSS3", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AWSMobileHubHelper(AWSContentManager.o)
     (maybe you meant: _OBJC_CLASS_$_AWSS3ContentProvider)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AWSS3GetPreSignedURLRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AWSMobileHubHelper(AWSContentManager.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AWSS3ListObjectsOutput", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AWSMobileHubHelper(AWSContentManager.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AWSS3ListObjectsRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AWSMobileHubHelper(AWSContentManager.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AWSS3PreSignedURLBuilder", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AWSMobileHubHelper(AWSContentManager.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AWSSNS", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AWSMobileHubHelper(AWSPushManager.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AWSSNSCreatePlatformEndpointInput", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AWSMobileHubHelper(AWSPushManager.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AWSSNSGetEndpointAttributesInput", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AWSMobileHubHelper(AWSPushManager.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AWSSNSSetEndpointAttributesInput", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AWSMobileHubHelper(AWSPushManager.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AWSSNSSubscribeInput", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AWSMobileHubHelper(AWSPushManager.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AWSSNSUnsubscribeInput", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AWSMobileHubHelper(AWSPushManager.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSDKAccessToken", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AWSMobileHubHelper(AWSFacebookSignInProvider.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSDKApplicationDelegate", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AWSMobileHubHelper(AWSFacebookSignInProvider.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSDKGraphRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AWSMobileHubHelper(AWSFacebookSignInProvider.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSDKLoginManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AWSMobileHubHelper(AWSFacebookSignInProvider.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GIDSignIn", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AWSMobileHubHelper(AWSGoogleSignInProvider.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SFSafariViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AWSMobileHubHelper(AWSQuickbooksAuthorizationManager.o)
      objc-class-ref in AWSMobileHubHelper(AWSAuthorizationManager.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

My Current Architecture : arm64,armv7,armv7s

I have probably spent 3 hours playing around with different things and I can't seem to find a solution... if you can lead me in the right direction I would appreciate it alot.

Comment: Are you using Cocoapods? If so, maybe take a look at this...
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=754901&#754901

Comment: I am using pods and I tried that but still getting the error..

Comment: Are you using Swift 3? AWS Mobile Hub does not yet support Swift 3.

Comment: So what should i do? Because i am using swift3

Comment: Swift 3 support has just been released, please download the MobileHub sample app again. Checking that it was generated with v0.10 template shown in any file's comments at the top. https://console.aws.amazon.com/mobilehub/home